# How to replace VBA formula error with blank

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA statement with an index-match formula.

```
GetMatch = WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Mapping").Range("$A$1:$E$10"), (WorksheetFunction.Match(Mid(Mystring, 1, InStr(Mystring, "_") - 1), Worksheets("Mapping").Range("$B$1:$B$10"), 0)), 4)
```

This returns an error (`#Value!`) when the value isn't found. That's fine, but this causes a problem when I try to use the result in any operation.

Example operation that fails: `CorrectMatch = GetMatch(MyString)`.

I've used `On Error GoTo 0`, `On Error GoTo Next`, `IsError`.

How can I return a blank in case of an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop using WorksheetFunction. Use Application.Index and  Application.Match instead and you can test the return with IsError.

```
function GetMatch(str as string)

    dim m as variant

    with Worksheets("Mapping")
        m = Application.Index(.Range("$A$1:$E$10"), (Application.Match(Mid(Mystring, 1, InStr(Mystring, "_") - 1), .Range("$B$1:$B$10"), 0)), 4)
    end with

    if iserror(m) then
        GetMatch = vbnullstring
    else
        GetMatch = cstr(m)
    end if

end function
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip and the solution @Jeeped! It works perfectly!